# Recycler view items duplicating everytime i m opening my Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here is my Adapter java class. I m retrieving data from firestore. Every time I am opening my activity, it shows the duplicate of files in mycollection. Every time I am opening, duplicated files are getting increased.

```
public class AccountsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AccountsAdapter.Accountsviewholder> {

        private List<Accountsmodel> list;
        private Context context;
        private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

        public AccountsAdapter(List<Accountsmodel> list, Context context, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
            this.list=list;
            this.context=context;
            this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Accountsviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.acc_pdf_item,null,false);
            return new Accountsviewholder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Accountsviewholder accountsviewholder, final int position) {
            accountsviewholder.aName.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();

        }

        public class Accountsviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            private TextView aName;
            private ImageView imageView;

            public Accountsviewholder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                aName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.aTV);
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.aIV);
                imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemClickListener.onClick(v,getAdapterPosition(),false);
            }
        }

    }
```

Below is my main activity. I have used the same method in another activity, but for direct downloading. Here I have used item click listener for web view method. so it's showing this error.

```
    FirebaseFirestore accdb;
    RecyclerView accRecyclerView;
    public static List<Accountsmodel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    AccountsAdapter accountsAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accounts);


        accdb=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        accRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.arecyclerdownloads);
        accRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        accRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        final ItemClickListener itemClickListener = new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Accounts_Activity.this, PDFActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("url",list.get(position).getLink());
                intent.putExtra("position",position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };



        accdb.collection("Accounts").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: task.getResult()){

                    Accountsmodel accountsmodel= new Accountsmodel(documentSnapshot.getString("name")
                            ,documentSnapshot.getString("link"),documentSnapshot.getString("fileextension"),documentSnapshot.getString("uploaddate"));
                    list.add(accountsmodel);
                }

                accountsAdapter = new AccountsAdapter(list,Accounts_Activity.this,itemClickListener);
                accRecyclerView.setAdapter(accountsAdapter);
            }
        })

                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(Accounts_Activity.this,"Error",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

 }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code where you are setting data to your adapter.

Comment: its posted...kindly check

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I don't think the issue is in the adapter, it's probably in how you retrieve data from Firestore.

In your case I assume you want to read data once, you should check out [this segment of documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

Now, instead of initializing your list in a constructor, you can create a setter for the field, which should be called in the on success listener.

Don't forget to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` method either in the setter or through adapter instance in your activity/fragment.